Why does the special character `?` need to be escaped in grep, but not `.` or `*`?
The only file in my current working directory is called test.txt and its content is simply:
This is a little test file.


Executing
grep -in * -e 'te.?t file'

gives no match.
But escaping ? works:
grep -in * -e 'te.\?t file'

gives match

Crazy: With the star *, things are the other way round!

Without escaping:
grep -in * -e 'te.*t file'

gives match
and escaping * does not work:
grep -in * -e 'te.\*t file'

no match

Why are the meta-characters ? and * treated differently with respect to escaping?

This is simply the syntax specification as used by grep. Without any additional flag, (GNU) grep uses Basic Regular Expressions, which require some metacharacters (in its pure form(1), braces) to be escaped. See also the grep manpage:

Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).

This means that in BRE mode, ? must be escaped if it is to be treated as a meta-character, whereas the same is not true for *. For a more "intuitive" behavior, you may want to switch grep to Extended Regular Expression (ERE) mode:
~$ grep -E 'te.?t file' test.txt
This is a little test file.
~$ grep -E 'te.\?t file' test.txt
~$ grep -E 'te.*t file' test.txt
This is a little test file.
~$ grep -E 'te.\*t file' test.txt


(1) Note that \|, \+ and \? in BRE mode are  actually nonstandard extensions but are supported by GNU and Busybox grep (and possibly others). See also the answer by Eli Minkoff.

On a further side note, as suggested by @Kusalananda, sed can help in debugging RegExp:
~$ sed -E 's/te.?t file/(&)/' test.txt
This is a little (test file).


Amusingly, with the default tools on mac, grep -e 'foo\|bar' matches the input foo, but e.g. sed -e 's/foo\|bar/xxx/' doesn't do the modification

Might be useful to note that egrep is the same as grep -E

@Kusalananda: Or for at least GNU grep (not sure on others), adding --color will colorize the matched part of the string.

@ShadowRanger Yes, but the colorisation is slightly misleading.  Compare sed 's/a/(&)/' and grep --color 'a' with the input abba for example. With sed it's clear that it's the first a in abba that matches, while grep highlights both a's even though the second a isn't actually part of the match.

grep uses Basic Regular Expressions by default, which are a more limited dialect, and don't support ? or + operators. The GNU and FreeBSD grep implementations do support them if backslash-escaped, but that's nonstandard. If you want grep to use Extended Regular Expressions, which are a more modern dialect that do support them, you can invoke it with the -E flag:
grep -in * -E -e 'te.?t file'

Or, with GNU grep specifically,
grep -in * --extended-regexp -e 'te.?t file'


Might be useful to note that egrep is the same as grep -E

@Dúthomhas I considered it, but it's been removed from the POSIX standard and may not be available on newer systems.
